# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 error:reached end of file while parsing

Tags: java, exception

Can anyone help me get rid of this Exception?

I'm trying to code a program that reads N pair and calculate and prints the sum of the pair numbers from the number 2 until the number written, if the number that was read is < 2 pop an error. Also I need the code to ask the user if he wants to repeat the process.

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0`

---

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Pares{
    public static void main (String[] args){

        int num;
        int npar;
        int rep;
        int suma = 0;

        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);

        do {
            System.out.println("Type a pair number");
            num=entrada.nextInt();
            npar=num%2;
            if (npar==0){

                for (int i = 0; i <= num; i = i + 2){
                    suma=suma+i;
                }

                System.out.println("The sum of the pairs : "+num+" are: " + suma);

            }else{

                System.out.println("Error");
            }

            System.out.println("Do you wish to repeat the program yes = 1/ no = 0");
            rep=entrada.nextInt();

        }while(rep==1);

    }
}
```

---

I seriously tried to look up for this error but I'm so new at coding that I could not understand the existing threads with the same error, thanks for the help!

Comment: Short answer - your array is instantiated with length 0, so you can't put anything in there. Long answer - there are a lot of errors, break your program up into much smaller chunks and get those working first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your `for` loop conditions are wrong. You need `i < n` everywhere. Currently none of your loops are executing except the last one where `i > np` becomes `1 > 0` and hence returns `true`. But, since you initialized your array with size `0` (`pares = new int[np]` becomes `new int[0]`) accessing `pares[0]` in the last loop throws the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment fixed it :)

import java.util.Scanner;
class Numero
{
public static void main (String[] args)
{
int num,npar,rep,suma=0;
Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
do {
System.out.println("Ingresar un numero par");
num=entrada.nextInt();
npar=num%2;
if (npar==0)
{
for (int i=0; i<=num; i=i+2){
suma=suma+i;
}
System.out.println("La suma de los numeros par: "+num+" son: " + suma);
}
else {
System.out.println("Error");
}
System.out.println("Deseas repetir el programa si = 1/ no = 0");
rep=entrada.nextInt();
}while(rep==1);
}
}

Comment: Is the code in the comments working now? If not, please update the question as it's difficult to read code in the comments. If yes, please accept the answer if it helped.

Comment: Yes I was really high and quickly understood got your answer thanks, just updated the code, I was really high when I wrote the first one so... Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You seriously need to check your code.

1. you initialized you `array` with length of `0`. don't do this.

   ```
       int n = 0;
       int np = 0;
       int num;
       int [] numero = new int [n];  // wrong, this initializes your array with length = 0
       int [] pares = new int[np];  // same here
   ```
2. your for loop conditions are wrong. Maybe the one you're after is:

   ```
       for (i = 1; i < n; i++)  // iterate like this
   ```
3. you're setting values to your array at basically the same location, which is `n`. consider using `i` instead

   ```
       numero[n] = num; //wrong, use i
   ```

I hope this points you to the right direction. good luck.